# How can I display repeated values only one time and have '-' if it repeats

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have some subqueries that retreives the same  values   for each PolicyNumber. How can I substitute repeated value with '-' and only display it one in a top row for each policy?
Right now I have this:
[image]
But I need something like this:
[image]

```
 SELECT
    -------------/* GrossPremium*/

           (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(tblFin_InvoiceDetails.AmtBilled), 0)
                 FROM tblFin_InvoiceDetails WITH (NOLOCK)
                 WHERE (tblFin_InvoiceDetails.ChargeType = 'P')
                 AND (tblFin_InvoiceDetails.InvoiceNum = INV.InvoiceNum))
                 AS GrossPremium

--------------/*CompanyCommissionPercentage*/

                ,((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(tblFin_InvoiceDetails.MGAAmt), 0)
                 FROM tblFin_InvoiceDetails
                 WHERE (tblFin_InvoiceDetails.ChargeType = 'P')
                 AND (tblFin_InvoiceDetails.InvoiceNum = INV.InvoiceNum))
                 +
                    CASE WHEN INV.Remitter = 'B' then
                    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(tblFin_InvoiceDetails.RemitterAmt), 0)
                     FROM tblFin_InvoiceDetails  
                     WHERE (tblFin_InvoiceDetails.ChargeType = 'P')
                     AND (tblFin_InvoiceDetails.InvoiceNum = INV.InvoiceNum))----------------RemitterCommission

                ELSE
                    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(tblFin_InvoicedItemsPayees.PayeeAmt), 0) 
                     FROM tblFin_InvoicedItemsPayees
                    INNER JOIN tblFin_PolicyCharges pc on pc.ChargeCode = tblFin_InvoicedItemsPayees.ChargeCode and pc.chargeType = 'P'   
                     WHERE (tblFin_InvoicedItemsPayees.InvoiceNum = INV.InvoiceNum and tblFin_InvoicedItemsPayees.PayeeGuid = INV.ProducerLocationGuid))
                END) * 100 / 
                NULLIF((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(tblFin_InvoiceDetails.AmtBilled), 0)
                 FROM tblFin_InvoiceDetails WITH (NOLOCK)
                 WHERE (tblFin_InvoiceDetails.ChargeType = 'P')
                 AND (tblFin_InvoiceDetails.InvoiceNum = INV.InvoiceNum)),0)
                 AS CompanyCommissionPercentage
FROM [tblFin_PayablesWorking] PW
INNER JOIN tblFin_Invoices INV ON PW.InvoiceNumber=INV.InvoiceNum
```

Comment: Although possible to do in SQL, this type of manipulation is usually better done in the application layer.

Comment: Yeah, but end user needs to extract data in Excel. Then check, make sure its ok and send it to whoever. Thats the probmem

Comment: It may be better to have a VBA script in Excel in that case, amusingly I was doing the same thing today and in Excel VBA it can be done in 5 lines with ease.

Comment: Thats sounds interesting but I never really code in VBA. Any good source for that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you do not mention you full query and Table schema, i will give your answer with two simple example.If you want replace your repeated value with `-` the follow this query(please change the columns name according to your needs).
**IF YOU WANT TO SELECT YOUR EXISTING TABLE:**

```
 ;with ts as (
    select  S1.[ProductID], row_number() over (partition by S1.[ProductID] order by S1.[ProductID]) as seqnum
    from (SELECT [SalesID],[ProductID] FROM [Sales]) AS S1 --Replace 'SELECT [ProductID] FROM [Sales]' with your Subquery and change the column accordingly 
)
SELECT
(case when seqnum = 1 then [ProductID] ELSE '-' end) as [ProductID] 
FROM ts
```

**FOR USING SUBQUERY:**

```
--CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales](
--  [SalesID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid()),
--  [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
--  [EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
--  [Quantity] [smallint] NOT NULL,
--  [SaleDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_SaleDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
-- CONSTRAINT [PK_SalesID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
--(
--  [SalesID] ASC
--)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
--) ON [PRIMARY]

--GO
--INSERT [dbo].[Sales] ([SalesID], [ProductID], [EmployeeID], [Quantity], [SaleDate]) VALUES (N'9498d566-e31b-4ac8-ab54-1c898471fba8', 2, 1, 1, CAST(N'2012-03-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
--INSERT [dbo].[Sales] ([SalesID], [ProductID], [EmployeeID], [Quantity], [SaleDate]) VALUES (N'69c7dff4-fbac-48d3-ae0a-5027c816acd2', 2, 2, 2, CAST(N'2012-04-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
--INSERT [dbo].[Sales] ([SalesID], [ProductID], [EmployeeID], [Quantity], [SaleDate]) VALUES (N'a40b9505-4a2c-4186-a89b-88a401248a58', 1, 1, 4, CAST(N'2012-02-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
--INSERT [dbo].[Sales] ([SalesID], [ProductID], [EmployeeID], [Quantity], [SaleDate]) VALUES (N'04856027-d7ad-40fe-889b-8d933595ffde', 3, 1, 2, CAST(N'2012-02-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
--INSERT [dbo].[Sales] ([SalesID], [ProductID], [EmployeeID], [Quantity], [SaleDate]) VALUES (N'173be2de-3b80-4a3d-8bcc-a74d0d70b3a9', 3, 2, 1, CAST(N'2012-03-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
--GO



;with ts as (

    SELECT  
    JOIN1.[SalesID] AS [SalesID]
    , JOIN1.[ProductID]
    , JOIN1.seqnum AS seqnum
    , JOIN2.[EmployeeID], JOIN2.seqnum2 AS seqnum2

    FROM
    (
    select row_number() over (order by S1.[SalesID] asc)  as RowNumber
    , S1.[SalesID] AS [SalesID]
    , S1.[ProductID] AS [ProductID]
    , row_number() over (partition by S1.[ProductID] order by S1.[SalesID]) as seqnum
    from (SELECT [SalesID],[ProductID] FROM [Sales]) AS S1 --Replace 'SELECT [ProductID] FROM [Sales]' with your Subquery ( For Example GrossPremium) and change the column accordingly. Remember you need some thing common for Iner join, in this case  [SalesID]
    )AS JOIN1 

    INNER JOIN
    (
    select row_number() over (order by S2.[SalesID] asc)  as RowNumber
    , S2.[SalesID] AS [SalesID]
    , S2.[EmployeeID] AS [EmployeeID]
    , row_number() over (partition by S2.[EmployeeID] order by S2.[SalesID]) as seqnum2
    from (SELECT [SalesID],[EmployeeID] FROM [Sales]) AS S2 --Replace 'SELECT [[SalesID]] FROM [Sales]' with your Subquery ( For Example CompanyCommissionPercentage) and change the column accordingly. Remember you need some thing common for Iner join, in this case  [SalesID]
    )AS JOIN2 

    ON JOIN1.[SalesID]=JOIN2.[SalesID]

)


SELECT
(case when seqnum = 1 then [ProductID] ELSE '-' end) as [ProductID]
,(case when seqnum2 = 1 then [EmployeeID] ELSE '-' end) as [EmployeeID]  
FROM (Select TOP 10000000 *FROM ts ORDER BY [SalesID] ASC ) AS ts -- Mentioning TOP is Must, or it will give Error
```

I do know why you are using `-` instead of `NULL`, `-` will take space

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to do it in SQL (you probably shouldn't it's pretty ugly) you could do something like this using LAG(). It relies on having a field that you can use to sort the records for each Policy Number, in my dummy data below I included a field called RecordID to do this.

```
SELECT
   PolicyNumber
  ,CASE
       WHEN LAG(GrossPremium) OVER(PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY RecordID) IS NULL
       THEN CAST(GrossPremium AS VARCHAR(MAX))
       ELSE '-'
   END GrossPremium
  ,CASE
       WHEN LAG(CompanyComissionPercentage) OVER(PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY RecordID) IS NULL
       THEN CAST(CompanyComissionPercentage AS VARCHAR(MAX))
       ELSE '-'
   END CompanyComissionPercentage
  ,CASE
       WHEN LAG(RemitterCommissionPercentage) OVER(PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY RecordID) IS NULL
       THEN CAST(RemitterCommissionPercentage AS VARCHAR(MAX))
       ELSE '-'
   END RemitterCommissionPercentage
  ,CASE
       WHEN LAG(RemitterCommission) OVER(PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY RecordID) IS NULL
       THEN CAST(RemitterCommission AS VARCHAR(MAX))
       ELSE '-'
   END GrossCommission
  ,CASE
       WHEN LAG(RemitterCommission) OVER(PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY RecordID) IS NULL
       THEN CAST(RemitterCommission AS VARCHAR(MAX))
       ELSE '-'
   END GrossCommission
FROM
( 
    -- Dummy data
    SELECT
           1234 PolicyNumber -- Partition the LAG() on the policy number.
          ,1 RecordID -- use this to order the LAG() function.
          ,8749.00 GrossPremium
          ,18 CompanyComissionPercentage
          ,10 RemitterCommissionPercentage
          ,874.90 RemitterCommission
          ,1574.82 GrossCommission
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
           1234
          ,2 RecordID
          ,8749.00
          ,18
          ,10
          ,874.90
          ,1574.82
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
           5678
          ,1 RecordID
          ,8749.00
          ,18
          ,10
          ,874.90
          ,1574.82
) x;
```